# Groovy - A Tale of Two Closure Invocations

Tags: string, groovy, closures

This works:

```
def myClosure = { println 'Hello world!' }
'myClosure'()
```

This does not work:

```
def myClosure = { println 'Hello world!' }
String test = 'myClosure'
test()
```

Why, and is there a way to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
test()
```

the parser will evaluate it as a call to the `test` closure/method without evaluating it as a variable first (otherwise you couldn't call any methods where you have a variable of the same name)

Instead, try:

```
myClosure = { println 'Hello world!' }
String test = 'myClosure'
"$test"()
```

#### Edit -- Class Example

```
class Test {
  def myClosure = { println "Hello World" }

  void run( String closureName ) {
    "$closureName"()
  }

  static main( args ) {
    new Test().run( 'myClosure' )
  }
}
```

#### Edit -- Class with a run closure example

```
class Test {
  def myClosure = { println "Hello World" }

  def run = { String closureName ->
    "$closureName"()
  }

  static main( args ) {
    new Test().run( 'myClosure' )
  }
}
```

Comment: "Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Test.myclosure() is applicable for argument types: () values: []" I also find it interesting that single quotes ('$test'()) don't even get that far.

Comment: @RandomHuman single quotes will not generate a templated GroovyString, (it will try to run the closure called `$test`).  As you're running this in a plain script, did you drop the `def` from the Closure definition as I have in my code above?

Comment: Dropping the `def` does seem to make it work...in a plain script. But I only set up one of those to have a self-contained example. In reality, all of this is living inside a `class`. I've discovered that dropping the `def` inside a `class` ends poorly.

Comment: Okay, after some experimentation, I think I've isolated what my problem was. In my `Test` class, my `run()` was itself a closure (as opposed to a method, like you have here). That doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @RandomHuman Added another example where `run` is a closure, and it seems to work too...

Comment: Hmm. That did work after several attempts. Not really sure what happened there. Maybe I had something stuck in my cache?